# Recursively moving files from multiple directories but ignoring one directory?

Tags: batch-file, recursion, directory, move

using this scenario, how would I move all files from all subfolders EXCEPT one folder (Archive)?

in c:\folder, I have folder called "Archive" and a bunch of randomly named folders will be coming in with txt files in them from an ftp server. I need to pull all contents from these randomly generated folders recursively while leaving the Archive folder alone. Current line of code for batch:

```
for /r %l in (*) do (IF NOT "%l"=="*Archive*" move /y %l c:\folder)
```

results in

```
c:\folder>(IF NOT "c:\folder\Archive\arctest.txt" == "*Archive*" move /y c:\folder\Archive\arctest.txt c:\folder )
1 file moved
```

I want this file to stay while the subfiles in all other subfolders move.

Comment: In linux, you'd do something very like this: `find . -path ARCHIVE -prune -i{} -exec mv -f {} c:/folder`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
for /r %a in (*) do @echo %~dpa|findstr /rvi "^.:\\[^\\]*\\archive\\$" >nul&& echo move /y "%~a" c:\folder
```

Comment: Hi Endoro: this simplification works too: `findstr /rvi "\\archive\\$" >nul&&`